# Shopify scripts giving strange error getting discount code

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

m working on a script that applies free shipping on specific shipping methods if the code "FREESHIP" is used. When I try to write this script I get an error that says:

```
Discount code requirements not met (Your cart)
Discount code requirements not met (Empty cart)
Discount code requirements not met (No customer)
```

The code I'm using:

```
Input.shipping_rates.each do |shipping_rate|
  if (shipping_rate.source == "fedex" && shipping_rate.code == 'FEDEX_GROUND') || (shipping_rate.source == 'usps' && shipping_rate.code == 'Priority')
    if Input.cart.discount_code && Input.cart.discount_code == "FREESHIP"
      shipping_rate.apply_discount(shipping_rate.price * 1, message: "Discounted shipping")
    end
  end
end

Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the discount code you are trying to use is not a valid code for the items in your cart If you swap out the items in cart and/or add a customer that should resolve the issue.